# Cannot return a card markup from the callback function of a universal action

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm just trying to get started with the sample addon Google describes here for extending the compose UI:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui

However when I run it I'm getting this error:

> Error with the add-on. Run time error. Cannot return a card markup
>   from the callback function of a universal action.

I have not setup any universal actions in my manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "oauthScopes":[
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"
    ],
  "gmail":{
    "name": "My Mail Merge",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/label_googblue_24dp.png",
    "composeTrigger": {
      "draftAccess": "METADATA",
      "selectActions": [
        {
          "text": "show UI",
          "runFunction": "buildImageComposeCard"
        }
      ]
    },
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
      ],
    "primaryColor": "#42585F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#42585F4"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Below is Code.gs:

```
function getInsertImageComposeUI(e) {
  return [buildImageComposeCard()];
}

function buildImageComposeCard() {
  // Get a list of image URLs to display in the UI.
  // This function is not shown in this example.
  var imageUrls  = [
    "https://mail.google.com/1",
    "https://mail.google.com/2",
    "https://mail.google.com/3"
    ];

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('My Images');
  for (var i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++) {
    var imageUrl = imageUrls[i];
    cardSection.addWidget(
      CardService.newImage()
      .setImageUrl(imageUrl)
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                        .setFunctionName('applyInsertImageAction')
                        .setParameters({'url' : imageUrl})));
  }
  return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
}

function applyInsertImageAction(e) {
  var imageUrl = e.parameters.url;
  var imageHtmlContent = '<img style=\"display: block\" src=\"'
  + imageUrl + '\"/>';
  var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
  .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
                            .addUpdateContent(
                              imageHtmlContent,
                              CardService.ContentType.HTML)
                            .setUpdateType(
                              CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT))
  .build();
  return response;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working either. I'd move on to something else if I were you.  Perhaps someone here will have a better answer but this example harkens to the days a decade ago when it was pretty much impossible for one with average intelliigence to even consider having a chance at figuring out how an example actually works.

Comment: Haha.  Well, I would find a Gmail addon quite useful to my employer so am motivated to find a way to work.  Will reach out to Google directly and see if they can help.  Stackoverflow is their 1st line of support for apps script stuff, but not the last.

Comment: By no means do I know as much as many other volunteers here so all is not lost yet.  I have written Gmail Addons but not composer addons.

Comment: I too was able to get the sidebar stuff to work, just not the compose stuff.

Comment: Any updates from google? or with developing the addon?

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file, `runFunction` has to be set to `"getInsertImageComposeUI"`,

Also, in the code file, `CardService.ContentType.HTML` has to be one of

```
CardService.ContentType.MUTABLE_HTML
```

or

```
CardService.ContentType.IMMUTABLE_HTML
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Already set the runFunction and ContentType to what you suggested but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error message and couldn't get that example to work. However, I created a simpler Hello-World example that actually works. I think it is more useful for newbies to start with. Don't forget to set the `runFunction` in the manifest to `getComposeCard`.

```
function getComposeCard(e) {   return [buildComposeCard()]; }

function buildComposeCard() {
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();   
    var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Test Header');   
    testVar = ['item1', 'item2'];   
    for (var i = 0; i < testVar.length; i++) {
        var item = testVar[i];
        cardSection.addWidget(
          CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(item));   
   }   
   return card.addSection(cardSection).build();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's way too late, but the problem can be fixed by simply wrap the result of `buildImageComposeCard` as array

```
return [card.addSection(cardSection).build()]
```